# Why only one warning in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, warnings

I want a warning raise for each problem detected in a loop, but the warning is only raised once, the first time. For example :

```
import warnings

for i in range(10):
   print i
   warnings.warn('this is a warning message')
```

I expect :

```
0
UserWarning: this is a warning message
1
UserWarning: this is a warning message
2
UserWarning: this is a warning message
3
UserWarning: this is a warning message
4
```

but the result is :

```
0
__main__:4: UserWarning: this is a warning message
1
2
3
4
```

Why do I have only one warning? How can I get a warning for each iteration?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is by design. See the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html:

> Repetitions of a particular warning for the same source location are typically suppressed.

You can override this behavior by adding a filter with the keyword `"always"`, as in:

```py
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter('always', UserWarning)
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    warnings.warn('this is a warning message')
```

Comment: What it is "source location" in this context?

Comment: @adosar The module name and the line number. It is explained in the documentation I linked in the answer: _"default: print the first occurrence of matching warnings for each location (module + line number) where the warning is issued"_

Answer (score 10):

From the [`warnings` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html):

> Repetitions of a particular warning for the same source location are typically suppressed.

This is by design.

I'd not use the `warnings` module if you want your message to be printed *always*; you could reset the filters (using [`warnings.resetwarnings()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.resetwarnings), but that's very much **not** recommended as you'd discard any user-configured filters too. You could add an explicit filter that always allows the message with the [`warnings.simplefilter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter):

```
warnings.simplefilter('always', UserWarning)
```

but I'd just write to `sys.stderr` directly instead.

Comment: Actually `resetwarnings` won't solve this particular question because it resets the warning filter to the default behavior, which is to suppress repeating warnings. One should specifically force the warning filter to print the warning everytime using `always` filter.

Comment: Actually, the phrasing "a particular warning" is ambiguous. I noticed that if the warning message is variable, for example if it is `"message %d" % i` in the OP example, it will be repeated...

Answer (score 6):

It'd already mentioned in the other answers that, by default, each warning is printed once for each source file where it occurs.  However, you could change that easily from the command line.  Invoke the interpreter by saying [`python -W all`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W):

```
$ python -W all
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 16 2014, 23:42:21)
[GCC 4.5.3] on netbsd6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import warnings
>>> for i in range(10):
   print i
   warnings.warn('this is a warning message')... ...
...
0
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
1
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
2
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
3
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
4
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
5
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
6
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
7
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
8
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
9
__main__:3: UserWarning: this is a warning message
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The default filters prevents multiple occurrences of your warning - you can override the filter using simplefilter.

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("always")
for i in range(10):
    print i
    warnings.warn('this is a warning message')
```